# window.find() not behaving same in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Part of web page contains the tree which can be expandable. 
If tree is too big, it will be kept in the division. 
This division holds all tree elements and it has the scroll-bar to see all elements.

And i am using the web-browser's window.find() in the java-script to find the elements.

To view the above page i am using different browsers:Mozilla-Firefox and google chrome.

Problem:
Mozilla browser able to find the text and moving scroll-bar is moved according to the location of the text.

Chrome browser able to find and highlight/selected the text and its UNABLE to move the scroll-bar to particular location, and we were scrolling the scroll-bar manually to go to the highlighted location.

Expected behavior: Chrome browser should behave same as Mozilla-Firefox, that is scroll-bar should be moved /down/up according to the selected text.

Can you help us on this?

Comment: The `window.find()` API was never a standard, and it's only supported by Firefox and WebKit browsers. Both the Firefox and WebKit teams would prefer to remove the API rather than fix it.